# Angular2 - Error with Routing

Tags: angular, angular-router

I've inherited an Angular2 application. It's a custom built IT ticketing system. 
We have a main menu (main.component) which users can see a list of their assigned tickets. They click a link to take them to the detail page of that ticket. On the ticket page (ticket.component), the user clicks "Save and Exit" once changes have been made. This will then send a post request to a RESTful API - with a number of properties about the ticket. This is completed via a custom service (ticketService.SaveTicket). This returns a subscription. Once the post data is complete, I want the application to navigate back to the main menu. Below is the method attached to the click event of the button "Save & Exit"

```
public saveClick(): void {
    var ticketData =
      {
        'ID': this.id,
        'AssignedTo': this.AssignedToSelect,
        'Status': this.StatusSelected,
        'Category': this.CategorySelected,
        'UsersAffected': this.AffectedSelected,
        'AdviseWhenCompleted': this.AdviseToSelect
      };
    this.savingTicket = true;
    let that = this;

    this.ticketService.SaveTicket(ticketData).subscribe(x => {
      this.savingTicket = false;
      this.router.navigate(['main']);
    }, err => {
      debugger;
      swal('Aw no!', 'An error has occurred saving this ticket', 'error');
      this.savingTicket = false;
    });
  }
```

Whenever the user clicks this, the following error appears in the console:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/components/ticket/ticket.component.html:28:24 caused by: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null
```

Obviously due to the error, the app does not navigate to 'main'. The browser windows also goes completely blank (indicating a JS error).

To be honest, I have no idea which parentElement it is referring to. I believe the culprit lies with the this.router.Navigate line, as when I comment it out the errors do not appear and the browser doesn't go blank.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this would occur? Any suggestions are much appreciated!

EDIT: Below is a snippet of the ticket.component.html - starting from line 27

```
<td style="text-align: right; width: 70%;">
    <span class="selectAutoResponse">Select Auto Repsonse:</span>
    <kendo-combobox [data]="autoResponse" [placeholder]="'- Select Value -'" [value]="selectedAutoResponse" [textField]="'ValueText'" [valueField]="'ID'" style="width: 350px" (valueChange)="handleAutoResponseChange($event)"></kendo-combobox>
</td>
```

EDIT: Below is a full extract of the console errors:

```
:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3064 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/components/ticket/ticket.component.html:28:24 caused by: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null
Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/components/ticket/ticket.component.html:28:24 caused by: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null
    at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:992:33)
    at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1239:20)
    at ViewWrappedError.WrappedError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1297:20)
    at new ViewWrappedError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6167:20)
    at View_TicketComponent3.DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12385:27)
    at View_TicketComponent3.DebugAppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12344:22)
    at ViewContainer.destroyNestedViews (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12476:41)
    at View_TicketComponent1.destroyInternal (/AppModule/TicketComponent/component.ngfactory.js:2598:15)
    at View_TicketComponent1.AppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:11986:18)
    at View_TicketComponent1.DebugAppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12341:42)
    at ViewContainer.destroyNestedViews (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12476:41)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_TicketComponent0.destroyInternal (/AppModule/TicketComponent/component.ngfactory.js:2907:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:11986:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12341:42)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_TicketComponent_Host0.destroyInternal (/AppModule/TicketComponent/host.ngfactory.js:33:19)
ErrorHandler.handleError @ :3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3064
:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3069 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ :3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3069
:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3070 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/components/ticket/ticket.component.html:28:24 caused by: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null
Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/components/ticket/ticket.component.html:28:24 caused by: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null
    at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:992:33)
    at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1239:20)
    at ViewWrappedError.WrappedError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1297:20)
    at new ViewWrappedError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6167:20)
    at View_TicketComponent3.DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12385:27)
    at View_TicketComponent3.DebugAppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12344:22)
    at ViewContainer.destroyNestedViews (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12476:41)
    at View_TicketComponent1.destroyInternal (/AppModule/TicketComponent/component.ngfactory.js:2598:15)
    at View_TicketComponent1.AppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:11986:18)
    at View_TicketComponent1.DebugAppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12341:42)
    at ViewContainer.destroyNestedViews (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12476:41)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_TicketComponent0.destroyInternal (/AppModule/TicketComponent/component.ngfactory.js:2907:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:11986:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12341:42)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_TicketComponent_Host0.destroyInternal (/AppModule/TicketComponent/host.ngfactory.js:33:19)
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:665:31) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:636:17) [angular]
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:713:17 [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3971:41) [angular]
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:366:36) [angular]
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:166:47) [<root> => angular]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:546:35) [<root>]
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:25) [<root>]
ErrorHandler.handleError @ :3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3070
zone.js:522 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/components/ticket/ticket.component.html:28:24 caused by: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ViewWrappedError Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/components/ticket/ticket.component.html:28:24 caused by: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null
    at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:992:33)
    at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1239:20)
    at ViewWrappedError.WrappedError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1297:20)
    at new ViewWrappedError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6167:20)
    at View_TicketComponent3.DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12385:27)
    at View_TicketComponent3.DebugAppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12344:22)
    at ViewContainer.destroyNestedViews (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12476:41)
    at View_TicketComponent1.destroyInternal (/AppModule/TicketComponent/component.ngfactory.js:2598:15)
    at View_TicketComponent1.AppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:11986:18)
    at View_TicketComponent1.DebugAppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12341:42)
    at ViewContainer.destroyNestedViews (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12476:41)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_TicketComponent0.destroyInternal (/AppModule/TicketComponent/component.ngfactory.js:2907:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:11986:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12341:42)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_TicketComponent_Host0.destroyInternal (/AppModule/TicketComponent/host.ngfactory.js:33:19)
consoleError @ zone.js:522
zone.js:524 ZoneAwareError
```

Comment: Could you also show the file ticket.component.html? Try show us the area where this error seems to pop up (likely line 28).

Comment: Thanks @DanielH.J. have updated the question

Comment: Hmm...I don't see anything wrong with the html at this point. Let's try this... say if you comment out this.router.navigate, when you call ticketService.SaveTicket(ticketData), does it save successfully and call the success callback, an error pops up and the error callback is called, or an exception is thrown and the whole JavaScript breaks? If possible, also show any other errors that comes up on the console :)

Comment: hi @DanielH.J., the success callback seems to be called (with or without the navigate line commented out) - i confirmed this by sticking a debugger command directly prior to it - which up until that point in the code, had no errors. The error callback fires correctly too, as I shutdown the API just prior to clicking save & exit, thus forcing the error to occur. The whole javascript only breaks when it reaches that this.router.navigate. Having said that I've just spotted a further error on the console - which may provide more clues? Will edit my original question

Comment: Ben has given an answer and I think that's definitely a possibility. Are you able to access the route 'main' from the browser window without any errors?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I definitely can (just tested it). I responded to ben and I think it may be along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear (from the code you posted) but I bet your issue is coming from the "kendo-combobox" failing to initialize properly after saving the ticket. Look inside that component and make sure it has a default model set to an empty model (usually inside ngInit or it's constructor.)

Comment: Thanks ben, I think the problem is larger (or of a different nature) - I commented out the kendo-combobox and found it produced the same error, but on a different line (line 13). Line 13 is <div class="ticket-left" *ngIf="ticketInfo"> - the kendo-combobox falls inside this div. The object ticketInfo is definitely not null though , as I've confirmed with a debugger statement just before the navigate function (thus the result of the ngIf should result in a value, or true). This ngIf was put in place to only render the HTML once the result from the API had returned data. Would this be the cause?

Comment: In that case, it might be some object is null when you execute the navigate back to main component. You get no errors when you don't call navigate?

Comment: Correct, no errors when I comment out the navigate function

Comment: That means there is something not setup right in the main component.